# Robocopy unilog output is gibberish

Tags: unicode, robocopy

I tried to get robocopy in Windows 7 to generate a Unicode log, since I have files with Unicode characters. The command I used:

```
robocopy C:\mysource D:\mydest /mir /unilog:backup.log /tee
```

File the copy works and the onscreen output is correct, the log file itself just contains gibberish. This is regardless of whether I use the Command Prompt or the Powershell.

What gives? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is also my experience.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39740131/11942268

Answer (score 7):

## Bug in XP27. Try downgrade to XP26.

It appears to be a bug in the `XP27` version of RoboCopy (which comes with Windows 7).

In version `XP26` (which comes with Windows Vista) `/UNILOG` produces a perfectly readable Unicode log file for me.

If you don't have a copy of Vista laying around [EasyRoboCopy](http://www.tribblesoft.com/Pages/EasyRoboCopy.aspx) also comes with the `XP26` version. (I haven't actually tried EasyRoboCopy itself, just extracted `robocopy.exe` out of its setup file using `WinRAR`.)

Answer (score 2):

At a glance, I'd say the file written by Robocopy while using the `/UNILOG` and `/TEE` switches contains a UTF-16 little-endian byte order mark followed by an ISO-8859-1 terminal typescript.

To make it readable, I did the following in Ubuntu:

```
dd if=robocopy.log ibs=1 skip=2 obs=512        | # Strip the byte order mark
  iconv --from-code ISO-8859-1 --to-code UTF-8 | # Convert to UTF-8
  col -b > robocopy_utf-8.log                    # Interpret control characters
```

The resulting file matches what I saw in the Windows command prompt.

*Further reading:* man [`dd`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dd), man [`iconv`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iconv), man [`col`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=col)

Comment: Any way to do similar conversion in windows? I have tried this conversion in pipe in PowerShell, but with no success:`([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode).GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::Convert([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591), [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode, ([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591)).GetBytes($_)))`

Comment: This works!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the (binary) file output on Win7, the /UNILOG option is useless.  It writes the standard UNICODE BOM (FFFE), but then proceeds to write all narrow characters *EXCEPT* for the options line (e.g., /BYTES /S /COPY:DATS ...), which is actual unicode. After that, it reverts back to ANSI chars, and it is *not* UTF-8, either; i.e., if you have a filename with a wide character in the path, it is converted to a narrow '?' character.

Apparently no interest in fixing it from MSFT, since it's been this way for some time, and I have all updates.

Comment: There is no such thing as "actual unicode" encoding. Did you mean UTF-16/UCS-2? It's MS fault to boot for naming this "unilog" in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my unreadable, Unicode-format Robocopy log files in Windows (which were accidentally created by appending normal Robocopy output to Unicode output from Out-File in PowerShell), as follows:

In PowerShell:

```
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('C:\Temp\RoboCopyLog.txt')
$len = $bytes.Length
#Remove the Unicode BOM, and convert to ASCII
$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes,2,$len -2)
$text
```

The above code may not work for all file sizes!

(Credit for code: I adapted code from this post by Ferdinand Prantl: [Stackoverflow - Read/Parse Binary files with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672092/read-parse-binary-files-with-powershell)

Comment: This works if the output doesn't contain Unicode characters; otherwise, those characters are converted to ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

## Use UTF-8 code page, then run winword converter

If your file or directory names contain Unicode characters then before issuing the Robocopy command with the `/unilog` parameter use the `chcp 65001` command. (Code page [65001 is UTF-8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756).)

Once you have the mangled Unicode log, just open it up in MS Word as `Unicode (UTF-8)` and save it:

[image: MS Word File Conversion Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the command in Powershell goes something like this:

```
robocopy C:\mysource D:\mydest /mir | Out-File backup.log
```

The workaround is that you use Out-File instead of built-in /unilog parameter.
You will get exactly the same log file, but now it will be properly written in unicode.

Comment: Sure it will be unicode, but there will be no special unicode characters. It's just ASCII output translated to unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `chcp` command before robocopy command, with the right code page.

for UTF-8 (not working with robocopy & Hebrew and maybe more languages):

```
chcp 65001 | Out-Null
```

for Hebrew:

```
chcp 1255 | Out-Null
```

Full code page list:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/code-page-identifiers

Comment: Does not work for robocopy /log switch